# PHP MySQL Only Printing Last Row in Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to get different output when you run the exact same query from PHP vs. PHPMyAdmin? When I run

```
$sql = "SELECT IF(PersonA=200, PersonB, PersonA) AS Person 
FROM People 
WHERE PersonA=200 OR PersonB=200;";
```

I get the correct output from PHPMyAdmin but a different (incorrect) result from my PHP code above. The following is my SQL class I use.

```
<?php

class SQLQueryExecutor {

    private $queryString; 
    private $conn; 
    private $db; 
    private $host; 
    private $username; 
    private $password;

    public function __construct($queryString, $db, $host, $username, $password) {

       $this->queryString = $queryString;
       $this->conn = NULL;
       $this->db = $db;
       $this->host = $host;
       $this->username = $username;
       $this->password = $password;

   }

   // make connection to mysql database 
   public function makeConnection() {

    $this->conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db);

    if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error);
    } 
   } 

   // execute query
   public function executeQuery() {

    if ($this->conn != NULL)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $this->queryString);
        $rows = Array();

        if ($result !== False) // resource returned?
          {
               while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
           {
                  $rows= $row;
               }

               return $rows;
        }
    }

    return NULL;

   }

   // close sql connection
   public function closeConnection() {

    mysql_close($this->conn);

   } 
} // class 

?>
```

I call this class as follows...

```
$user = $_GET['User_ID'];
$sql = "
  SELECT IF(PersonA=$user, PersonB, PersonA) AS Person 
 FROM People 
 WHERE PersonA=$user OR PersonB=$user;";

 $newSQLQueryExecutor = new SQLQueryExecutor($sql, "blah","blah", "blah", "blah");
 $newSQLQueryExecutor->makeConnection();
 $rows = $newSQLQueryExecutor->executeQuery();
 $friends = Array("friends" => $rows);
 $newSQLQueryExecutor->closeConnection();

 print_r($friends);
```

The PHPMyAdmin prints all the correct rows but the PHP only prints the very last row.

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason to get different results assuming you're pointing at the same data source. Can you please provide more detail? Result A / B etc so that we can better understand your query?

Comment: did you try printing out the query to see if they are indeed exactly the same as you assumed

Comment: Yes, I printed it out and it was correct. Could it be the way it is executed at run-time? Not sure. I'm relatively new to PHP.

Comment: Have you checked quotation types etc?

Comment: So show us the result from the phpMyAdmin and the result from the PHP run and the data you are looking at in the database

Comment: Also show the PHP code that you use to process the result. It is likely that is where you are doing something wrong

Comment: What is in the incorrect result? Is it empty? Or does it return different result. For that matter, what does the successful result look like?

Comment: The correct result in PHPMyAdmin returns a number of rows that satisfy the query whereas in PHP it only returns the last row. I'll update my question.

Comment: Then you are overwriting the variables in the while loop and printing the result after the while loop finishes **Simples** Which is why I asked to see the PHP code you use to process the result

Comment: I'm not using any loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your issue, a mistake in the `executeQuery()` method

```
public function executeQuery() {

    if ($this->conn != NULL) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $this->queryString);
        $rows = Array();

        if ($result !== False) { // resource returned?
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $rows[] = $row;
    // amended       ^^
            }
            return $rows;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```